# JAVA java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, apache-httpclient-4.x

Receiving below exception using resttemplate doing a post call.
Restarting the service help the error go away for sometime but it gets back after some requests

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down
    at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:34) ~[httpcore-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.requestConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:269) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:176) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at brave.httpclient.TracingMainExec.execute(TracingMainExec.java:65) ~[brave-instrumentation-httpclient-5.13.9.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at brave.httpclient.TracingProtocolExec.execute(TracingProtocolExec.java:66) ~[brave-instrumentation-httpclient-5.13.9.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsStreamingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsStreamingClientHttpRequest.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:776) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:437) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at com.vanil.service.windriver.WindRiverTokenUtil.getWindRiverAuthToken(WindRiverTokenUtil.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.vanil.service.windriver.WindRiverTokenUtil$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$493c6bee.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(CacheInterceptor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.invokeOperation(CacheAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:421) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:345) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:64) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at com.vanil.service.windriver.WindRiverTokenUtil$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a2677659.getWindRiverAuthToken(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.vanil.service.windriver.folderapi.WindRiverFolderClientImpl.createFolder(WindRiverFolderClientImpl.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.vanil.service.windriver.folderapi.WindRiverFolderClientImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$51945e24.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-retry-1.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329) ~[spring-retry-1.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:209) ~[spring-retry-1.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-retry-1.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.annotation.AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-retry-1.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at com.vanil.service.windriver.folderapi.WindRiverFolderClientImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f7d3aa92.createFolder(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.vanil.service.generate.start.upload.accTaskUploadProvider.createFolderForacc(accTaskUploadProvider.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    ... 76 common frames omitted
```

Using `httpclient:4.5.13`

Creating resttempalte

```
@Autowired
    public clientImpl(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
    }
```

Connection pool is not managed manually but depends on default resttemplate and httpclient configs

Comment: Did you get a solution for this issue? I am facing the exact same issue. After server restart, the issue does not occur for sometime but later it starts again.